# ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Key can't be blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

After updating to Rails 4.0, I am getting this error.

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Key can't be blank):
  app/models/users_setting.rb:25:in `update_value'
  app/controllers/management_reports/employee_onboarding_controller.rb:35:in `update_filter_values'
  app/controllers/management_reports/employee_onboarding_controller.rb:57:in `prepare_to_read_data'
  app/controllers/management_reports/employee_onboarding_controller.rb:11:in `index'
```

This is the method:

```
def update_value options={}
  binding.pry
    self.update_attributes!({:value => options.inspect})
  end
```

pry shows me this:

```
[5] pry(#<UsersSetting>)> self.update_attributes!({:value => options.inspect})
   (5.0ms)  BEGIN
   (5.0ms)  BEGIN
   (4.8ms)  ROLLBACK
   (4.8ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Key can't be blank
from /Users/justinhung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/validations.rb:57:in `save!'
[6] pry(#<UsersSetting>)> options
=> {:status=>"-1", :client_id=>"-100"}
[7] pry(#<UsersSetting>)> :value
=> :value
[8] pry(#<UsersSetting>)> value
=> "{:status=>\"-1\", :client_id=>\"-100\"}"
[9] pry(#<UsersSetting>)> :value => options.inspect
SyntaxError: unexpected =>, expecting end-of-input
:value => options.inspect
         ^
[9] pry(#<UsersSetting>)> options.inspect
=> "{:status=>\"-1\", :client_id=>\"-100\"}"
[10] pry(#<UsersSetting>)> options
=> {:status=>"-1", :client_id=>"-100"}
```

Not sure how to proceed, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is it you expect this is doing? `self.update_attributes!({:value => options.inspect})`

Comment: Can you please post the schema of the table

Comment: From what version did you upgrade your Rails application? Did you only update the Rails version or did you do change any code too? What validations are there on that model?

Comment: @jvillian, I'm not too sure, I received this project from another person. When I comment it out, I am able to get to the page, and nothing is different from the Rails 3.2 version which is the what the site is currently on.

Comment: @spickermann I upgraded from Rails 3.2.18. I have changed some code, such as deprecations, etc. to get the server running and to access pages. I have also updated a number of other gems to fix some issues I have encountered. This is the validates line: ` validates :user, :key, :value, :presence => true`

Comment: @DeepakMahakale, I'm not too sure what you mean by schema of the table?

Comment: There is a validation that an `UserSetting` must have a `key`. Our `options` do not include a value for a `key`? Is `key` already set on the `UserSetting`?

Comment: This is probably because belongs_to relationships have become mandatory since RoR 4. Are you forgetting to set a related record?

Answer (score 2):

See **options** itself is a hash so you just need to pass options try,

```
self.update_attributes!(options)
```

where **status** and **client_id** are model attributes.

Key can't blank and value can't blank are the rails validation error messages coming because of maybe you set presence true for these two fields.

If you want to skip validation you can do the following so that when you update rails don't shout for key and value presence.

```
def update_value options={}
  self.status = options[:status]
  self.client_id = options[:client_id]
  self.save(validate: false)
end
```

Comment: unfortunately, that doesn't work, I get the error: `Validation failed: Key can't be blank, Value can't be blank`.